# How to unbind second slider effect in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have index page. On 404 page I inserted index page through the iframe. For timer i use the code below:

```
 var timer = setInterval(function () {methods._next(data,options)},3000);

 $("#centralPanelBorder, #leftBlock, #rightBlock").hover(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
 },
 function () {        
       timer = setInterval(function () {methods._next(data, options)},3000);
    })
```

This code works fine on the index page but on iframe - methods._next is doubled, and if I try hover and unhover - timer is not deleting, but multiplicate. How to resolve that? Thanks

UPD: resolved

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.timer` to `timer` in `hover()'s` second callback.

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {methods._next(data,options)},3000);

 $("#centralPanelBorder, #leftBlock, #rightBlock").hover(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
 },
 function () {        
    timer = setInterval(function () {methods._next(data, options)},3000);
 });
```

Comment: nope. i've tried different ways, with window.timer, this.timer but no way (

Comment: i resolved the problem - var timer = setInterval(function () {methods._next(data,options)},3000); is doubled in the different functions - thanks a lot